# How to implement cross-platform custom window?

Tags: c++, gcc, user-interface, window, cairo

Okay, so, I have a C++ project I'm working on. I've created my own custom window using Cairo (I realize Cairo might not be the best for this application but it makes a lot of tasks that my GUI needs to do easier).

It controls the window size, minimizing and everything by itself, but when I create a borderless window to put it in, it still has an opaque background (my custom window has rounded borders).

How could I get the background to be transparent on at least the 3 most popular window systems? What are the platform-specific API functions that do this so that I can abstract it myself, or, is there a lightweight library that does this and will work with Cairo?